# Why does this logic work on my main loop, but not on a method?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry

I wrote this as a placeholder, knowing it woudnt work:

```
While(true)
    if (red > 1.0f)
        redinc = -0.01f;
    if (red < 0.0f)
        redinc = 0.01f;
    red += redinc;
```

This is inside my main loop, and i have no idea why, but **it works, red goes from 0 to 1**. But then, when moving the code to a method

```
void Move(float& a) {
    float ainc;
    if (a > 0.7f)
        ainc = -0.05f;
    if (a < -0.7f)
        ainc = 0.05f;
    a += ainc;
```

It doesent. It does exactly what I expected to happen in the first place, goes 0.7 - 0.65 - 0.7.

Has anyone encountered this before? Why does it work in the first place?

Comment: The code in the function doesn't have a loop.    You need to either include a `while` statement (or some other loop construct) in the function, or call the function within a loop.

Comment: The code starts out with an infinite loop: `while (true) if (red > 1.0f) redinc = -0.01f;`. It never changes the value of `red`. Is it missing some curly braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a` is between `-0.7` and `+0.7`, `ainc` is declared but never initialised, so you will basically at best be adding a random number to `a`, at worst having a random crash.

In the main loop, `redinc` keeps the last value it was assigned since it is in scope for the whole loop, so it will work.